# Display console log on a UI Text component

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I need to display my console errors in a UI Text in my Unity Project, so, when I make a formal android build, if there's some error I could know.
Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-logMessageReceived.html

Comment: Do you want to display an error message to a user or for debugging purposes?

Comment: If you have Android Studio and Android SDK then you can use the monitor.bat.

Comment: There's also [Consolation](https://github.com/mminer/consolation) for a lightweight in-game debug console. (I haven't tried [Log Viewer](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/log-viewer-12047), though it looks like it has more features.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`Application.logMessageReceived`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-logMessageReceived.html) event is invoked when there is a log. Subscribe to it then get the text from it and assign it to the Text component. For older version of Unity, `Application.RegisterLogCallback` should be used.

```
public Text logText;

void OnEnable()
{
    Application.logMessageReceived += LogCallback;
}

void OnDisable()
{
    Application.logMessageReceived -= LogCallback;
}

void LogCallback(string logString, string stackTrace, LogType type)
{
    logText.text = logString;
    //Or Append the log to the old one
    //logText.text += logString + "\r\n";
}
```

---

This will get your started and let you view the log on the Android device but if you want a complete solution, use the [*Log Viewer*](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/log-viewer-12047) plugin from the assetstore. It has a complete UI system that lets you view the log like the Console log from the Editor:

[image]
<sub>(source: [cloudfront.net](https://d2ujflorbtfzji.cloudfront.net/package-screenshot/f199a14c-2d53-4c77-8f3d-16c321ee8a77_scaled.jpg))</sub>

Comment: I just wanted to suggest to use `Log Viewer` until I saw you already did it here ;)